# NSRegularExpression find pattern with optional part

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Here is the thing :

I have a file storing some datas, following the pattern :

```
item1:value1 item2:value2 item3:value3 // \n
item1:value1 item2:value2
item1:value1 item2:value2
// and so on...

// item3:value3 IS OPTIONAL
```

Then I store the datas of the file in a `NSString`, to deal with them.

I want to match value2 but the thing is that the pesence of `item3:value3` is optional in each line.

So I tried to use the `?` regular expression operator but I'm not sure about the way to use it.

So typically I tried to match the following pattern (which doesn't work, ofc):

```
@"item1:.* item2:(.*) (item3:.*)?\n"
```

Better explained, I want to regroup the 2 conditions in 1 :

```
@"item1:.* item2:(.*) item3:.*\n" // Case 1 : item3:.* present in the line
@"item1:.* item2:(.*)\n"          // Case 2 : item3 not present
```

*Note that I already made a personnal function that returns all matches in an `NSMutableArray`.*

I hope this is clear enough :/

Thanks for help and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like there were a couple of errors in that regular expression: I'll run through them now.

Firstly, you are trying to match the end of a line with "\n". This will work fine if your string ends in a new line, but will not match the last line otherwise. To fix this, use the "$" symbol, and make sure to pass `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` as the `options:` parameter when you instantiate the regular expression, like:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"item1:.* item2:(.*?)(?: item3:.*)?$"
                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
                                                  error:nil];
```

The `$` symbol is called an anchor, and by default matches the end of the string. Its opposite is the `^` anchor, which matches the start of the string. If you pass the `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` option, however, these anchors change behaviour to match the start and end of any line of the string.

Secondly, you're using plane parethensis, `()`, to group the "item3:" part, but you don't want to get this group out as a result of the match (a "capture"). If you don't want to "capture" the text in a group, write the group like `(?:...)`. Strictly, using plane parenthesis will work (and does in your example), but means that the regular expression engine must do more work, as it needs to keep track of what's inside the capture group so that you can access it when the method returns (in your case with `rangeAtIndex:2`).

Thirdly, you misplaced a space in your regular expression (just before the open parenthesis of the item3 group), such that your regular expression would only match a line if the data of item2 ended in a space or the line had a item3 entry. This is what made it seem as though the `?` wasn't working in your regular expression, and would have solved your main problem on its own. The space needs to be inside the group that is followed by the question mark, otherwise your regular expression will only match if the space is actually there!

And finally: the `*` operator is *greedy* by default, meaning that it will match as much as it possibly can. This has the effect of making the `(.*)` part of your regular expression eat up all of the text until the end of the line, and the regular expression will still match, because the `(item3:.*)?` part is optional. Placing a `?` after the `*` (i.e. `.*?`) changes the way that the `*` works, making it *lazy* so that it matches as little text as possible, meaning that, if possible, the regular expression will prefer to match the item3 part of a line with the `(item3:.*)?` part of the regular expression over the `item2:(.*)` part of the regular expression.

So your regular expression would look like:

```
@"item1:.* item2:(.*?)(?: item3:.*)?$"
```

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced a space there. Try that. Am I correct in understanding that your problem is that you only want the value for item2 to be returned, and nothing else, but your attempt returns too much?

Comment: I want to match item2 in the cases :
1. item3 is present
2. item3 is not present
Because item3 is optional so it can be here or not ! :)

Comment: What happens when you try the above regular expression? Does it not match anything?

Comment: It returns the last match :D

Comment: Does the smiley face indicate that that is what you want, or do you want every match? Is returning the last match a result of the regular expression, or the method that you're using?

Comment: My method store all matches in an Array and then I check `[myArray description]` to see what is in it. So I want to get all matches. So no it's not what I want, but anyway i appreciate your help :).

Comment: Aha! If you pass NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines as the options: parameter when you instantiate the NSRegularExpression, that should fix the problem!

Comment: Damn you good Johnny. Can you please improve your answer by explaining your ideas with the `?` and the `$` ? Would be great :)

Comment: You seem to have the right idea with the `?`, you just misplaced that space, and that's what made it seem that the `?` wasn't working!

Comment: Ok but I don't get the role of the `$`…

Comment: Ok so it matches the line break (`\n`) ? And I don't get your idea with the `?` of the item2… :/

Comment: `lat:.* long:(.*?)(com:.*)?$` does have the same effect (so without `(?:...)`). The `?` of item2 do everything I think but I don't get why…

Comment: Ohh, I completely forgot about that! I'll address that in my question now too :P

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ;) Good to know that `?` changes `*` behaviour !

Comment: The same thing happens (and the `?` does the same thing) with the `+` operator, which matches one or more as opposed to zero or more, as the `*` does. And, in fact, this happens with any operator that can match different numbers of things. The `?` its self is greedy (but in this case it comes second and so the `*` is greedy before the `?` has the chance to be greedy) and you can make a lazy `?` by writing `??`.

Comment: Ok ;). Don't you think that your `(?:...)` is a bit useless ? Because if I choose the index `1` in my pattern (what I did), it will only keep `.*?` inside the 1st set of parenthesis so we should not care about this `?:` in the second parenthesis.

Comment: Well, it's "useless" in the sense that it's more characters in the regular expression, but using `(...)` is likewise "useless" in that it creates an extra unused and unnecessary capture group. I tend to stick to `(?:...)` if I don't need to get the contents of the group, because sometimes it's faster, and most of the time it is easier to get the right group out if there aren't unnecessary groups clogging up the return value.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have reliably consistent patterns in you text you can analyze the patterns to build your regular expression and Objective-C logic.

First identify substrings that reliably separate elements you are interested in. 
Assuming from what is pasted, 
First you might separate each item by new line separator. 
Make an array of lines. This is useful if each series of numbered items are related somehow.

Next, it looks from what you've pasted that you might have multiple ways to identify the portions of each line that you are interested in.

Again, you really need to simply have some idea of what might be in your strings and what won't be in them.

You could use the white space to further identify separate items, if and only if the items themselves will not contain white space. 
If you can only verify that an item is defined like this, then you have a bit of work:
Definition:
an item is the string immediately following a string with the pattern : 
Beginning of line or a single space followed by "item" followed by a number 1, 2, or 3 followed by a ":"

The end of the value string is delimited by an end of line or the delimiter beginning another item.

From this you should be able to replace the definition of the pattern with a regular expression.

You will have an easier time if you break this into multiple steps using programming language logic and conditionals and don't try to do everything in a single regular expression.

Comment: I already thought about that but I prefer try to use the RegEx and `NSRegularExpression`class because I know there is a lot of powerfull features in theses tools that I don't know yet. And I know my way will be heavier than if I use theses tools up to the hilt.